# Autowiring does not work in Symfony 5.1 demo project with PHP 7.4.4

Tags: symfony

I am attempting to bootstrap a simple Symfony 5.1 project and I cannot get dependency injection / autowiring support to work. I am quite at the end of my abilities and need help. Here is what I do:

1. Create empty project by running: `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton testProject`
2. Create files `testProject/src/Util/Rot13Transformer.php` and `testProject/src/Service/TwitterClient.php` with contents copy-pasted from this tutorial page: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html
3. Check the services in console by executing
   `php bin/console debug:container App\Util\Rot13Transformer` and `php bin/console debug:container App\Service\TwitterClient`

Output for both is:

```
------
  Public           no
  Synthetic        no
  Lazy             no
  Shared           yes
  Abstract         no
  Autowired        yes
  Autoconfigured   yes
------
```

4. Open file `testProject/public/index.php`, add a new line after other use statements:

`use App\Service\TwitterClient;`

Add a new line just before kernel initialization at the end of the index file with following content:

`$client = new TwitterClient();`

5. Run this file on console with
   `php public/index.php`

I always end up with error:

> Too few arguments to function
> App\Service\TwitterClient::__construct(), 0 passed in
> /Users/oink/Documents/Development/testProject/public/index.php on line
> 27 and exactly 1 expected

Why? Should not autowiring take care of Rot13Transformer argument? Why does not it work? This is a vanilla example made on the basis of skeleton and with scripts copied/pasted from Symfony web site.

My PHP version is 7.4.4

Thanks!!

Comment: This is a very common beginner mistake with many many answers.  Just hard to search for though you could perhaps try looking for the error message.  I'll give you a hint: what do the docs say about the relationship between the PHP new operator and the Symfony DI container?

Comment: Got it, thank you! Should not use `new` to initialize object but instead get it from the DI container `$kernel->getContainer()->get($ServiceName)`

Comment: It would be better to inject it into a console command or controller action.